# VueJS Reactive Array with filters

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a notification list with two filters (Show All, Show Unread). I load all of the notifications when the component is created and then call the filter Show All.

```
created() {
   axios.get('user/notifications').then(response => {
       this.notifications = response.data;
       this.showAll();
   }).catch(e => {
       console.log(e);
   });
 },
```

Here are the Show All and Show Unread methods:

```
showAll() {
     this.filteredNotifications = this.notifications;
},
showUnread() {
    this.filteredNotifications = _.filter(this.notifications, notif => {
          return notif.read_at === null;
    });
},
```

I'm iterating the array like this:

```
<li v-for="notif in filteredNotifications">
    <span @click="toggleNotification(notif)"></span>
</li>
```

And here I'm toggling the notification:

```
toggleNotification(notification) {
    axios.put('user/notification/' + notification.id + '/toggle', {_method: 'PUT'}).then(response => {
         notification.read_at = notification.read_at == null ? true : null;
    }).catch(e => {
         console.log(e);
    });
}
```

I'm trying to make it so, when I'm in the Show Unread filter, whenever I toggle a notification it will be removed from that filter. It can't be removed from the original array because when I click on Show All, I have to see all notifications.

At the moment, when I'm in the See Unread Filter, if I toggle a notification it changes the notification `read_at` to true, but doesn't remove it from the list. Only when I click the filter again does it refresh.

I could easily solve this by putting a flag in each filter, and then in the toggleNotification I could check which flag is active and call it's method manually, but that's too dirty for me. Any help?

Comment: I think the reason is showUnread method will not trigger when the data inside filteredNotifications is changed. 
you can try to put the showUnread method to computed. In Vuejs, the computed will auto re compute when the depended data is change.

Answer (score 1):

Your methods look like okay. But if you want to notification mark as read then send request to back end database to set read_at = currentDate. When the request ended succesfully just exclude read notification by its index from this.filteredNotifications array and Vue will re render based on new array.

```
<li v-for="(notif, index) in filteredNotifications">
    <span @click="toggleNotification(notif, index)"></span>
</li>
```

Then in your method:

```
toggleNotification(notification, index) {
    axios.put('user/notification/' + notification.id + '/toggle', {_method: 'PUT'}).then(response => {
       notification.read_at = notification.read_at == null ? true : null;
       this.filteredNotifications.splice(index, 1)
    }).catch(e => {
       console.log(e);
});
```

If you want to re render based on response, then in response send back the all unread notifications and set this.filteredNotifications = response.